# How can I convert to varchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I need the output as varchar and the number is saved as 1 or 1.5 .... But for now my number is saved as 1.00000. I cannot change the design of the table and this field can be either string or number

So ,I try to convert in the following way :

```
SELECT CAST( ISNULL( TRY_CAST( a.field AS FLOAT) , 'NAME') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) FROM #TABLEA a
```

My idea is that if it is a number then it convert to float, otherwise it will replace it with 'NAME'

But i get the error : 'Error converting data type varchar to float'
if I replace 'NAME' with a number there will be no errors.

Does anyone have any ideas for this problem?
Thanks !

Comment: CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), a.field)

Comment: It's a bad design to save a number as `VARCHAR` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The `ISNULL()` has two different arguments, one a `float` and one a string (the constant `'NAME'`).  That is cause the problem.

I would suggest `case` logic for this:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(a.field AS FLOAT) 
             THEN a.field ELSE 'NAME'
        END) 
FROM #TABLEA a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try casting the converted float back to nvarchar;

```
cast(TRY_CAST( a.field AS FLOAT) as nvarchar(50))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

> [ISNULL: Returns the same type as check_expression.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

And you are trying to use two different types. I'd recommend to use COALESCE, but you would have the same problem since it [returns the data type of expression with the highest data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), and FLOAT is upper VARCHAR in [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). So, my two cents will go for something like this:

```
#If you can cast it, then use that field. Use "Name" otherwise.
SELECT (CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(a.field AS FLOAT) IS NOT NULL  
             THEN a.field ELSE 'NAME'
        END) 
FROM #TABLEA a;
```

Comment: Thank for all your answers!